# Print select values of python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I have the following nested dictionary which is composed of several devices along with two values per device. I am trying to display these in a table within a flask page.

```
[(
    {u'host': u'Spine1', u'type_instance': u'sysName', u'type': u'counter', u'value': 0, u'time': u'2016-11-09T21:44:00Z'}, 
    {u'host': u'Spine1', u'type': u'uptime', u'value': 104473.72, u'time': u'2016-11-09T21:44:00Z'}, 
    {u'host': u'Spine1', u'type': u'gauge', u'value': 249119600.0, u'time': u'2016-11-09T22:39:12Z'}), 
    (
    {u'host': u'leaf1', u'type_instance': u'sysName', u'type': u'counter', u'value': 0, u'time': u'2016-11-09T21:44:00Z'}, 
    {u'host': u'leaf1', u'type': u'uptime', u'value': 104466.68000000001, u'time': u'2016-11-09T21:44:00Z'}, 
    {u'host': u'leaf1', u'type': u'gauge', u'value': 249069928.0, u'time': u'2016-11-09T22:39:12Z'}), 
    (
    {u'host': u'leaf2', u'type_instance': u'sysName', u'type': u'counter', u'value': 0, u'time': u'2016-11-09T21:44:00Z'}, 
    {u'host': u'leaf2', u'type': u'uptime', u'value': 104465.77, u'time': u'2016-11-09T21:44:00Z'}, 
    {u'host': u'leaf2', u'type': u'gauge', u'value': 249119680.0, u'time': u'2016-11-09T22:39:12Z'}
)]
```

My problem is I can not get the jinja for loop to select the proper key,value pairs and Im at a lost on how to approach this.

Here is my config from the flask page to display the table.

```
<table>
<th>Device</th><th>Uptime</th><th>Mem Used</th
 {% for host in HostAll %}
   <tr>
    {% for item in host %}  
      {% for key, value in item.iteritems() %}
        {% if key == 'host' %}
          <td><a href = "{{ item.host }}"><b>{{ item.host }}</b></a></td>
        {% elif key == 'value' %}
          <td> {{ value }}</td>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```

And here is how the table looks
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxlyC.png)

I would like to have each row show "Host", "Value", "Value" from each of the lines for each device.

Am I on the right track or is there a better way to approach this?

As always thanks!!

Comment: If you only want to print two keys, why do you need to iterate over the entire dictionary? Just print out those two keys.

Comment: Im not opposed to those options. I guess Im just green enough to not grasp how and have been running in circles reading docs and other solutions. I dont mind putting in the research and work if I could just get pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured this out. The nesting is what is throwing me and I was having issues with matching on one k,v and displaying another.

```
    <table>
<th>Device</th><th>Uptime</th><th>Mem Used</th><th>CPU Used</th><th>Playbook</th>
 {% for host in HostAll %}
   <tr>
    {% for item in host %}  
      {% for key, value in item.iteritems() %}
        {% if value == 'sysName' %}
          <td><a href = "{{ item.host }}"><b>{{ item.host }}</b></a></td>
        {% elif value == 'uptime' %}
          <td> {{ item.value }}</td>
        {% elif value == 'gauge' %}
          <td> {{ item.value|filesizeformat(false) }}</td>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
```